# UISearchBar with custom scope bar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I make custom scope bar like this:
[image]

Comment: so did you found out any solution ?

Comment: @BishalGhimire It's custom view, imitation of UISearchbar. I decided to not spent a lot of time to recreate it.